# Using PyGithub, how do I get the last known update time for a repository?

Tags: python, pygithub

I've been developing a portfolio website and part of the data for the projects (like the project summaries and the latest update times) are obtained through PyGithub using the project title.

When I call for an update to my database it compares the time (which is stored as a string but converted to a datetime object for comparison) stored to the time that I get from the Repository()._updated_at.value. The following is the function I use to get the project information through PyGithub.

```
def access_project(title: str) -> dict:
    auth = Auth.Token(os.environ.get("GITHUB_TOKEN"))
    g = Github(auth=auth)
    repo = g.get_user().get_repo(title)
    my_project = {
        'title': title,
        'description': repo.description,
        'last_updated': repo._updated_at.value,
    }
    print(repo._updated_at.value)
    g.close()
    return my_project
```

The issue I'm having is that the value from repo._updated_at.value is the exact same value that I have stored in my database, despite the fact that I just updated one of my projects just around half an hour ago after a couple months of having left it untouched. I don't really understand why this is, my best guess would be that maybe the update time of the repository itself is different from that of just the files that I updated.

Either way, I'd like to avoid having to compare EVERY files' latest update time and picking out the latest if possible. Any suggestions?

Comment: Just for clarification, I could use the link to the project repository and quickly just scrape the latest update time since GitHub has the latest update time pasted at the top of the repository next to the number of commits.

I'd just like to avoid doing this and am asking if PyGithub has a simple function or class attribute that stores the information I want without going through every file.

Answer (score 0):

Found it! What I wanted was the Repository().pushed_at value, which gives me the time of the last push to my repository. So for my code I'd just change `repo._updated_at.value` to `repo.pushed_at`